# Broadcasting webinars to and from Ubuntu

Tags: citrix

I've recently attended an online workshop using Citrix GoToWebinar, a service that allows someone to broadcast their desktop and audio out to all members connected to the presentation as well as receive audio and screencasts from those attendees , and the experience was unbelievable, and I was wondering if there was any such service/software available on Ubuntu. Points to consider include, but are not limited to:

- Web services or local applications.
- Free (as in beer) or paid.
- Free (as in speech) or proprietary.
- Ease of use
- Ease of setup
- Any other point that anyone can thing of

Comment: So basically there are lots of screencasts and one main one, am I right? Try Webex... Not sure if that is what you want, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a long time Ubuntu user and also work for Citrix Online who make GoToWebinar.  I just wanted to let you know that we are working on support for Linux currently, it's something I'm pretty excited about and will definitely be announcing on my blog once it's ready :)

Comment: W00t! That's the best answer I could have hoped for. Thanks a lot. do you have any sort of timescale for the release, Will we see it any time in 2011?

Comment: 2014 update here : https://twitter.com/gotowebinar/status/487295024338853888

Comment: As of attempting to screencast a month ago.... still waiting for Ubuntu support I believe.